# Need help for a regular expression to rewrite a URL path (for Cherokee)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need help to write a regex to redirect a URL path from:

`http://mydomain.com/files/2012/10/image_4-1.png`

to:

`http://mydomain.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/5/files/2012/10/image_4-1.png`

... the `wp-content/blogs.dir/5` (it static) needs to be added.

Just can't figure it out... Can anyone help with the regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(files/2012/10/image_4-1\.png)$ wp-content/blogs.dir/5/$1 [L,R=302,NC]
```

**PS:** If you want to add `wp-content/blogs.dir/5` before every path then use this rule:

```
RewriteRule (?!^wp-content/blogs.dir/5/)^(.*)$ wp-content/blogs.dir/5/$1 [L,R=302,NC]
```

Comment: Hi, can't figure it out. The portion "2012/10/image_4-1\.png" is dynamic. I tried to tweak it but it does not work. Can you help?

Comment: 2nd version of my rule is full generic and I have also tested that on my end. If it doesn't work for you pls provide some details like what is not working and also provide relevant portion of your access.log and error.log files.

Comment: Yup, I have resolved this problem by rewriting "^/files/(.*)" to "http://mydomain.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/5/files/$1".